# Count number of characters and appear time in c++

Tags: c++

Assume that i have an array of character contains a text message, example:

```
"abccddcabbef"
```

Now i want to count the number of charracter and appear time of each character. The result will be two arrays:

```
char a[6] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'}    // array of character
int b[6] = {2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1}   // appear time
```

which is the best way to do this?

sorry about my english!

Comment: Please post the code which you have put down, and point out the problem you are facing...

Comment: the problem is that if i create an array with the fixed size of 128 (in case that the text message contains all the ASCII character), there will be many useless space if the text message just contains few characters like i mentioned above.

Comment: @tuankhoa1996 Use a `std::vector`, two respectively.

Comment: i wasn't allowed to use anything except array! :(

Answer (score 1):

Why not do this: create an `std::unordered_map`, with its keys being the character and its values being an int.

so for example:

```
    unordered_map<char, int> map;
    string inputText;
    for (int i = 0; i < inputText.size(); ++i)
        {
           map[inputText[i]]++;
        }
```

Now you can iterate through this map, and you can find out the actual characters that you have seen so far as the map's keys, and the amount of times each character has appeared so far as the map's value.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the assumption is that the input string `str` is smaller than 128, then you know there are always going to be less than `strlen(str)` unique chars.

Therefore you could do something like:

```
std::string str = "abcabx";
char a[str.length()];
unsigned size[str.length()];

// zero arrays
memset(a, 0,  str.length());
memset(size, 0, str.length() * sizeof(unsigned));

unsigned num_unique = 0;
for (char x : str) {
  unsigned i = 0;
  while (a[i] != '\0' && a[i] != x) ++i;
  num_unique = std::max(i+1, num_unique);
  a[i] = x;
  ++size[i];
}

for (unsigned i = 0; i < num_unique; ++i) {
  std::cout << a[i] << " - " << size[i] << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is based on the assumption that you know the array lengths you will need for results in advance. If you do not know that info in advance, I would suggest using List or ArrayList of char.

But, based on your question, this is what I would do.

```
int aCurrentIndex = 0;
for (i = 0; i  < origArray.length; i++) {
    if (!a.contains(origArray[i])) {
        a[aCurrentIndex] = origArray[i];
        b[aCurrentIndex] = 1;
        aCurrentIndex++;
    }
    else {
        b[a.indexOf(origArray[i])] = b[a.indexOf(origArray[i])] + 1;
    }
}
```

In the else statement, you might be able to use the following, but I haven't tested it, and don't want to tell you wrong.

```
b[a.indexOf(origArray[i])]++;
```

Comment: so the size of 128 is the only way if just use array?

Comment: I see your issue, and my initial response would be yes. In that case, do some preliminary work building array 'a' with the ascii characters, then preliminary work building array 'b', size 128, with all values as 0. Then run only the else portion of my code since you will not need to build a, only find the current character from original, and increment that character count in b. This is because of having to declare array size before adding values. If you could use List, you would not be hindered by sizing result arrays before looping original.

Comment: Are you sure you can't use list to get values, then call yourList.toArray() once it's all built from original array? The original can definitely start as an array, but a and b could start as Lists that you turn into arrays. I.E. arrA = lstA.toArray();

Comment: yes! i was'n allowed to include any library to my project. Seem like i don't have choice. Thank you! :)

Comment: @tuankhoa, if one the answers here helps you, please accept it as the answer to help others that come across this page. Thanks!